# Знаки за метки или знаки по меткам?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, локализация, метки, знаки

Наблюдается некоторая несогласованность при описании знаков, связанных с метками. Например, для [золотых знаков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=gold):

> [image: знаки]

Стоит заметить, что в глоссарии transifex *"tag badge"* рекомендуется переводить и вовсе как *"тематический знак"*.

Имеет смысл навести порядок.

Comment: Глоссарию транзифекса не стоит доверять, он просто автоматически предлагает вариант на основе уже имеющихся. Т.е. даже если в базе переводов будут ошибки, транзифекс предложит их повторить.

Comment: @NickVolynkin значит, есть смысл скорректировать [глоссарий](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/glossary/ru/). Он всё-таки вручную заполняется. А термин *"тематический знак"* вроде и вовсе не прижился.

Comment: Хм, я немного другое имел в виду. Там есть фича с автоматически предлагаемым переводом на основе имеющейся базы переводов.

Comment: «Тематический знак» точно не прижился.

Comment: @NickVolynkin что-то не заметил там автоматического перевода.

Comment: @NickVolynkin снова эти ваши модератоские ссылки с вязаными шапочками.

Comment: Ой, я ж вроде сразу удалил. А я не то удалил, вот что.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать вариант "за". В частности, это согласуется с пунктами [общей страницы описания знаков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges):

- Знаки за вопросы
- Знаки за ответы
- Знаки за участие
- Знаки за модерацию

Comment: Поддерживаю. Это согласуется с общей практикой использования предлога с существительными, обозначающими признание заслуг: «медаль за...», «премия за...», «благодарность за...». Второй вариант ближе к школьным оценкам: «пятёрка по...».